# how to change time format with radio buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a digital clock for a school project here is the code i have so far (note the radio buttons do nothing) i have been trying everything i can think of to have the radio buttons change how the time is displayed in the label but this is all I have working for now

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import *
from time import *

class App():
    def __init__(self):
    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.title('Digital Clock')
    self.label = Label(text="", font= ('times', 40, 'bold'), bg= 'blue')
    self.label.pack()
    self.update_clock()
    self.button1 = Radiobutton(self.root, text='12 hour format', value=1)
    self.button1.pack()
    self.button2 = Radiobutton(self.root, text='24 hour format', value=2)
    self.button2.pack()
    self.root.mainloop()

def get12hour(self):
    now = datetime.now()
    time = now.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p').lstrip('0')
    return time

def get24hour(self):
    now = datetime.now()
    time = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S').lstrip('0')
    return time

def update_clock(self):
    time = self.get12hour()
    self.label.configure(text=time)
    self.root.after(200, self.update_clock)

app=App()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your radio buttons need to share a common variable that you can check.  Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import *
from time import *

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Digital Clock')
        self.label = Label(text="", font= ('times', 40, 'bold'), bg= 'blue')
        self.label.pack()

        self.which_button = IntVar()  # share this between all radio buttons in a group
        self.which_button.set(1)  #initialize
        self.update_clock()
        self.button1 = Radiobutton(self.root, variable=self.which_button, 
                                   text='12 hour format', value=1)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2 = Radiobutton(self.root, variable=self.which_button, 
                                   text='24 hour format', value=2)
        self.button2.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def get12hour(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        time = now.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p').lstrip('0')
        return time

    def get24hour(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        time = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S').lstrip('0')
        return time

    def update_clock(self):
        time = self.get12hour() if self.which_button.get() == 1 else self.get24hour()
        self.label.configure(text=time)
        self.root.after(200, self.update_clock)

app=App()
```